# Azure Functions Logging

Tags: c#, .net, azure-functions, azure-functions-runtime, azure-functions-core-tools

In Azure Functions you use host.json to configure logging. However, the logging options/sections are unclear to me. Can someone help?

Per this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-host-json

```
  "logging": {
        // FILE CONFIG?
        "fileLoggingMode": "debugOnly"
        "logLevel": {
          "Function.MyFunction": "Information", // where is this log?
          "default": "None"
        },
        // INSIGHTS CONFIG
        "applicationInsights": {
            "samplingSettings": {
              "isEnabled": true,
              "excludedTypes" : "Dependency;Event",
              "includedTypes" : "PageView;Trace"
            },
```

1. Is the FILE CONFIG section used for logging in "log stream"? or is the INSIGHT section?
   [image]
2. What is 'default' vs 'Function" log level?

I assume Filesystem logs is what controlled via FILE CONFIG section, correct?

3. What configuration is used for "Monitor" section of Azure Functions?, is it FILE CONFIG?
   if so, If I wanted to see only errors under "Monitor" section would I set  Function.MyFunction": "Error" or "default"?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. `FileLoggingMode` is used to generate the ***logs*** in **azure portal** or in a **local Environment**. The different modes in `“fileLoggingMode”` are

**“debugOnly”:** This level will generate logs when the function app is running on ***Azure Portal***. This is the default mode.

**“always”:** This mode is used to generate logs in ***local environment*** as well as when running on ***Azure Portal***. This [code](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-host/blob/d87c8b0a972800434455b74e8253bbf2675956b9/src/WebJobs.Script/Host/FileLoggingStatusManager.cs#L19) reference can be helpful to understand it better.

**“never”:** This mode does ***not*** generate any logs.

When the `“fileLoggingMode”` is set to ***“always”*** the log file generated when running in local environment is stored in `“C:\Users{user}\AppData\Local\Temp\LogFiles\Application\Functions\Function{Function_Name}”,` the path can be referenced here in the [Host Settings code](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-core-tools/blob/b2157d366244c7a72f208261ba8d3c5acbda8f81/src/Azure.Functions.Cli/Common/SelfHostWebHostSettingsFactory.cs#L15). If you are running the function app as docker/container in your local premises you can change the path by updating the [host configuration code](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-host/blob/65cf07688b6974219b90d4fc57d420c5226dc4fb/src/WebJobs.Script.WebHost/Configuration/WebScriptHostConfigurationSource.cs#L59).

The `fileLoggingMode` is still in issue see [here](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/issues/59008#issuecomment-658965287)

2. **Default** Vs **Function** log is both are same level check the below json

In a logging loglevel we have Parameters `default/function/…` we where mention the Which type of log can we need to get like *(error, information, trace, ….)*

```
{
"logging": {
    "fileLoggingMode": "always",
    "logLevel": {
        "default": "Information",
        "Function": "Error"
        }
    }
}
```

Refer: [Configure monitoring for Azure Functions | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/configure-monitoring?tabs=v2#configure-log-levels)

3. In a default it get the log information of what you added in a parameter `(host.json).` If you are using `"default": "Error"` you will get the ***Error logs*** by default.

If you are using below configuration by **default** it will get the `Information Log` and **Funcition** get the `Error log`.

```
"default": "Information",

"Function": "Error"
```