# Success count and error cound is always 0 when I use monitor for my published azure function

Tags: azure-functions

If I use Application insight for my azure function I can see that it works. Screen shot here.
[image]

I have published my azure function to azure and it works perfect. I have switched on Appligation insight but when I look at monitor for my azure function
I can see that both success count and error count is always zero. I know that my azure function works because it insert record in my database. I have waited much longer than 5 minutes but nothing happens. My azure function is done in .Net Core 3.1.

I mean that since all monitoring for Azure Functions is done with Application Insights by default it should update success count and error count

Answer (score 0):

> I have referred this [MSDOC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/analyze-telemetry-data) to configure Application Insights after deployment, [telemetry](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/asp-net-core?tabs=netcorenew%2Cnetcore6) and stack [reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68931661/azure-functions-logging).

**Code** :

```cs
try
{

var  length  =  name.Length;
}
catch  (Exception  ex)
{
log.LogError(ex,  "An error occurred: {errorMessage}",  ex.Message);
return  new  StatusCodeResult(StatusCodes.Status500InternalServerError);
}
if  (string.IsNullOrEmpty(name))
{
log.LogWarning("No name provided in the request.");
}
else
{
log.LogInformation($"Name received from the request: {name}");
}
```

**In Local Output:**

[image]

- Deployed the [application](https://i.imgur.com/lHzuQSX.png) we can find the motor log in motor tab.

[image]

[image]

[image]

- Make sure to enable application insights from the MSDOC, Steps in Stack reference, and test the application again.

**In  Application Insights** :

**Output:**

[image]

[image]